# Does an SQL Update Look different from any other query in showplan.out?

Tags: ms-access, profiling, ms-access-2003, showplan.out

I'm using an access database, and I'm monitoring it using `showplan.out`.

I'm trying to figure out which field in which table a certain checkbox applies to.  (I can't look at the form so don't ask)

I start monitoring; change the value of a checkbox; click save; and then stop.

Then I start monitoring again; change the value of the same checkbox, click save; and stop monitoring.

To my surprise both `showplan.out` files are identical (I did a diff), and neither of them have the value `-1` in them, as vba checkboxes usually indicate.

All of the queries in question are marked as `--- temp query ---`.

Assuming that the GUI form uses SQL `UPDATE` to change the value the checkbox value, what would that look like in `showplan.out`?

I've seen a few things in `showplan.out` that kind of look like it is checking the Primary key to see if it can fit another record in the table with distinct values, but I'm still a unsure of what constitutes an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` here:

```
--- temp query ---

- Inputs to Query -
Table 'T_SkillLevelGroups'
    Database 'E:\XXX\xVisitrax_BE.mdb'
Table 'T_SkillLevelGroups_Map'
    Database 'E:\XXX\xVisitrax_BE.mdb'
    Using index 'slg_Key'
    Having Indexes:
    slg_Key 4007 entries, 7 pages, 10 values
      which has 1 column, fixed
    PrimaryKey 4007 entries, 8 pages, 4007 values
      which has 1 column, fixed, unique, clustered and/or counter, primary-key, no-nulls
- End inputs to Query -

01) Restrict rows of table T_SkillLevelGroups
      by scanning
      testing expression "T_SkillLevelGroups.slg_GroupName In ("ZZZ","XXXX")"
02) Inner Join result of '01)' to table 'T_SkillLevelGroups_Map'
      using index 'T_SkillLevelGroups_Map!slg_Key'
      join expression "T_SkillLevelGroups.slg_Key=T_SkillLevelGroups_Map.slg_Key"
      then test expression "slgm_SkillLevel='someskill'"
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask - are you sure the checkbox is used in the query? I don't see any filter in your showplan for a boolean field. Can you write VBA code in the database? If so, you can get your hands on the SQL in the form.

Comment: Oh well that's just an example, there's actually alot more in the `showplan.out`.   How can I tell if it's a boolean field?  (I already searched for `bool` and `boolean`)

Comment: It's proprietary and locked so I can't get into the VBA for the form...or the form itself.

Comment: You need to search for a string that looks like either '=0' or '=-1'

Comment: Yeah I didn't find either...must be buried in the code for the form.... :p

Comment: If you see no difference in the showplan regardless of checked/unchecked, then I don't think that field is used in the criteria. Here is a sample I have of one (note the reference to a field and the value): 01) Restrict rows of table tblEmployee
      by scanning
      testing expression "tblEmployee.IsManager=-1"